# Proving $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$, where the $r_i$ are the roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

A very simple question. Saw this formula many places earlier, but how do we prove it?
$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$$ Where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of the quadratic.

P.S.- I have seen a "proof" using Vieta's formulas, but Vieta's formula itself requires this fact in its proof.

Comment: If you know the Factor Theorem, then it follows that $(x-r_1),(x-r_2)$ are factors of $ax^2+bx+c$, and then an argument on the degree shows that the degree of the remaining factor is $0$, and equating $x^2$ coefficients, we see we need the last factor to be $a$.

Comment: The Factor Theorem is also straightforward to prove.

Comment: @a1402 Yeah OK! But is there a more direct proof?

Comment: It is not a formula, it is an identity

Comment: Appealing to factor theorem seems direct enough, else consider what could be the quotient and reminder when dividing the general quadratic $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ with $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$.  The remainder cannot have degree more than $1$, and we know the values at the zeros, and so on...

Comment: This started off in my head as trivial, then easy, then subject only to brute force or to other results. It's easy to prove by completing the square and calculating out $a(x−r_1)(x−r_2)$ but this seems like cheating. It seems like there should be a full and easy proof without relying on other results (like the factor theorem or Vieta) but I can't see what it is, and the other commenters don't seem to either.

Comment: @Blitzer Hence the question!

Comment: Yes - "good question" was what I was trying to say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For quadratic equation $$0=ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2},$$ its roots are $$r_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ Depending on the sign of $b^2-4ac$, the roots could be distinct reals, a multiple real, or distinct complexes. We actually do not need the fundamental theorem of algebra here, which is usually used for equations of higher orders (e.g., order $5$ or more).

Then we can evaluate it directly
\begin{align*}
a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)&=a[x^2-(r_1+r_2)x+r_1r_2] \\
&=a\left[x^2-\left(-\frac{b}{a}\right)x+\frac{b^2-(b^2-4ac)}{4a^2}\right] \\
&=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}\right)=ax^2+bx+c. 
\end{align*}
I guess people are overthinking about this question.

Comment: @Bernhard You used Vieta!

Comment: No, I didn't. I got the expressions for $r_1$ and $r_2$ and evaluated their sum and product directly.

Comment: @Bernhard Did not notice that initially, thank you!

Comment: You are highly welcome :)

Comment: @BernardPan I believed, first we use factor theorem to get the very basic identity the OP is asking proof for. Then we simplify and equate the coefficient of $x$ and constant term to get the sum of roots and product of roots. I don't think getting sum of roots by actually adding the two roots, we get from quadratic formula (requiring its own proof by completing the square) is more basic than the aforementioned.

Comment: Hi @AmanKushwaha, I agree with what you are saying. Your approach works generally and is essentially how we deal with the roots of polynomials over a general field. Nevertheless, I am not sure whether the OP really wanted this abstract solution, as this question is tagged with "precalculus".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that's what you want, but try factoring $ax^2+bx+c$ and you will have expressions for the roots.

Comment: The OP is asking in general, for any quadratic, how to show that $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: But that has to do with the fact that from the outset you must assume that it has roots, but on the way of knowing whether or not it has roots, you conclude that the conditions to find an expression of the roots, furthermore, factorization is a principle of polynomial arithmetic.

Comment: Every quadratic has 2 roots over $\mathbb{C}$ (counted with multiplicity).

Comment: Sure about the complexes they have a solution, but the workspace is not specified, but from the way you ask, I think it is about the real ones.

Answer (score 1):

What do you define as "roots" of the quadratic? If they are precisely the two (not necessarily distinct) values that make the quadratic zero, then it's as trivial as setting the factorised expression to zero and deducing that one or the other linear factor has to be zero. The two roots of the LHS correspond in some order to the two of the RHS, giving you the proof.

As to the fact there are two roots (including the case of a repeated root) of a quadratic, you have to use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra for that, and that is a fairly deep result.